# REST workitems in jBPM 6 lose query parameters sometimes when loaded in Workbench

Tags: jbpm

I find that if I put a REST workitem into a process, and then set the URL thus

```
Method=GET
Url=http://localhost/mytesturl/#{globalVariableSegment}/something?query1=#{variable}
```

that whilst that line is successfully saved into the BPMN file it works perfectly, with all the variables being translated to their appropriate values, however, frequently, when I load or save the BPMN file (and I can't work out exactly what does it) the Url will be overwritten as:

```
Url=http://localhost/mytesturl/#{globalVariableSegment}/something?query1
```

There is obviously something about the '=' which is upsetting the assignments editor in workbench, and causing it to sometimes terminate the string there.

Can anyone spread any light on this, or suggest workarounds? I've tried everything I can think of, including setting global variables and trying to "map" them. Anything other than an assignment (ie. equals) seems to cause the RestWorkItem to complain that Url is a required parameter.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No one seems to have an answer for this, right now - so for anyone searching, my current workaround is to pre-URLEncode the query parameters section of the string. That seems to work, and the workbench hasn't lost or screwed up any of my parameter strings since doing so.